# Problems with $_POST returning undefined index

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

First, yes I know there are other questions VERY similar to this one, but, none quite helped me.

The idea is to send the values via a POST where it should go to the DB and say if the user exists or not.
But i keep receiving the PHP error, with the use of `isset` and a ternary operator, I was able to not **receive** the error, but he still persists. for what i can see, the variables are there(formControlName), i'm really lost here.

ERROR:

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in /srv/http/database_vee/connection_php/connect_user.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: password in /srv/http/database_vee/connection_php/connect_user.php on line 12
{ "sucesso": false, "usuario": "" }
```

html form:

```
<form [formGroup]="formularioLogin" (ngSubmit)="login(formularioLogin.value)">

<ion-input placeholder="email"  formControlName="email" required="true"></ion-input>

<ion-input placeholder="senha"  formControlName="password" required="true"></ion-input>

<div class="flexbox-2-of-1">
  <ion-button fill="clear" type="button" (click)="cadastrar()">Cadastrar</ion-button>
  <ion-button color="dark" type="submit" [disabled]="formularioLogin.invalid">Entrar</ion-button>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
export class LoginPage {

  formularioLogin;

  constructor(private toastController: ToastController,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService,
    private storage: Storage) {

    this.formularioLogin = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: "",
      password: ""
    });
  }

  async presentToast() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Usuário não encontrado!',
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  login(dadosLogin: any) {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("email", dadosLogin.email);
    formData.append("password", dadosLogin.password);

    this.userService.login(formData).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);

      if (data.sucesso) {
        this.storage.set("user", data.user).then(() => {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/home");
        });
      } else {
        this.presentToast();
      }
    });

    console.log(dadosLogin);



  }
```

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    require_once("./connect_bd.php");

    $connect = AbreConexaoBD();
/* 
    $user_mail = (isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
    $user_password = (isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST['password'] : ''); 
 */
    $user_mail = $_POST["email"];
    $user_password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM tb_user
             WHERE user_mail = '".$user_mail."'
               AND user_password = '".$user_password."'";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        echo '{ "sucesso": true, "usuario": { "id": '.$user["id"].', "nome": "'.$user["name"].'" } }';
    } else {
        echo '{ "sucesso": false, "usuario": "" }';
    }

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` - see what's going on first. I don't know ionic, so my first assumptions could be wayyy off.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in /srv/http/database_vee/connection_php/connect_user.php on line 11
NULL

Comment: The error message is saved inside the $_POST variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because PHP automatically build the `$_POST` variable by parsing the POST data when they are sent in the form of a querystring. But Angular sends raw JSON.

If you want to access your POST data from the PHP script you need to do it like this :

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
try {
    $post = json_decode($input, 1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $post = $_POST;
}
$_POST = $post;
```

What I did personally is put this script in a file that's included in the index.php so that every request goes through it.